# Underscore.js - Filtering a json array based on a property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Below is my json array, and I'm trying to filter it based on active users.

```
var users = [{"name":"user1","isActive":true}, {"name":"user2","isActive":false}, {"name":"user3", "isActive":true}];

 $scope.filteredUsers = _.filter(users, function(user) { return user.isActive == true; });
```

I would want the output to be

```
 $scope.filteredUsers = [{"name":"user1","isActive":true}, {"name":"user3", "isActive":true}];
```

what am I doing wrong ? Is this the right approach or should I use _.where ? Thanks

Comment: It works. The `_filteredUsers` is exactly what you need it to be after running this code.

Comment: Isn't it `return user.isActive == true;`?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please see my comment in the answer below for more details about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why didn't you include that in your original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see any error in your approach except that you are filtering for isActive == false. If you want the active users you have to change your filter:

```
var activeUsers = _.filter(users, function(user) { return user.isActive });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question. I'm trying to use the same approach with in an angular controller. So, something like $scope.filteredItems = _.where(.....); It doesn't seem to work thus far. Let me check my code again.